# In VB.net why do only some different fonts be printed?

Tags: vb.net, printing, fonts

I'm using this code to print items to pdf file using:

```
gfx.DrawString(mstrPrintData(mnumCurrentItemNumber) & "", **fntPrintFont**, brushBrushes, New XRect((numLeftMargin + mnumIndentFromLeftMargin(mnumCurrentItemNumber) + numAdjuster + gnumLeftShift) * gnumWidthScale, (mnumThisYPosition(mnumCurrentItemNumber) + mnumLastHeaderYPosition - mnumYPositionReBase) * gnumHeightScale, gPage.Width.Point, 0), XStringFormats.TopLeft)
```

where fntPrintFont has been previously set as:

```
fntPrintFont = New XFont("Name of new font", 15, FontStyle.Regular)
```

The routine prints some of the fonts I've tried, but not the new 'Daniel' handwriting font the customer wants. I installed the Daniel font correctly. [Daniel font installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgMf2.jpg)

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Fonts. It may have a different font name than _Daniel_. E.g. _Arial_ has lots of different sub types, one of them being _Arial Standard_, which is what e.g. MS Word shows as _Arial_.

Comment: I did that and it prints a different font but not Daniel Regular. I tried Brush Script MT Italic and Ink Free Regular (both from Control panel/Fonts) and these failed. However, Rage Italic worked so we'll run with that. Thank you.